# Choosing JRE runtime environment in java 9 in eclipse oxygen version

Tags: java, java-9, eclipse-oxygen

I am trying to explore Java 9 features with Eclipse Oxygen Version. I have downloaded the java 9 and Eclipse Oxygen version.

But when I try to create a new java project Java SE 1.9 is not available in the list of JRE Execution environment.

How to proceed further? Any help would be appreciated.

Choosing Runtime environment
[image]

Choosing default JRE??
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to proceed further? Any help would be appreciated.

Try to make use of the option ***Use default JRE***. Though this seems to be not configured on your machine currently.*("Unknown")*

You can try out the [Java9 example](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Java9/Examples) and take a look at [Greg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46453401/1746118) on how to support it with the current Eclipse version.

***Note***: For the patch to work with you would have to install [java-9-support-beta-oxygen](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-9-support-beta-oxygen) as well.

Comment: Without the patch I mention in my answer Eclipse does not recognise Java 9 as a JRE/JDK at all.

Comment: @greg-449 Agreed. Updated.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have installed the latest patch which was given by @greg . I am not able to choose default JRE as well. It says "Target is not a JDK root. System library not found". Attached image in the question regarding the issue that i face while choosing default JRE.

Comment: @kamal Updated the answer. You would have to install java-9-support-beta-oxygen as well to use the patch.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.0) does not support Java 9. You can install a patch to add support from Eclipse market place [see here](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-9-support-beta-oxygen/)

Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) is scheduled to be released on 11th October (2017) with full Java 9 support.

More details in the Eclipse wiki [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have installed the latest patch. Still I am not able to see JRE 9 in the list. I am not able to choose default JRE as well. It says "Target is not a JDK root. System library not found". Attached image in the question regarding the issue that i face while choosing default JRE.

Answer (score 0):

After you have installed the Java 9 support for Eclipse Oxygen through the Marketplace you also have to edit your eclipse.ini. Eclipse has to be started through the Java 9 JDK, so add/change existing to:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin\javaw.exe
```

You will also need an additional vmargs argument:

```
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

After this you should be able to select a Java 9 JDK and it will be detected as such.

See eclipse wiki for detailed informations:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9

Comment: The [Java 9 support page](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-9-support-oxygen/) says "The Java™ 9 support also works when the IDE is launched with a Java™ 8 VM. There is no need to switch Java™ 9 VM for that."