# Unable to run a java application after upgrading eclipse Oxygen 1A.RC1

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9, eclipse-oxygen

Recently I have upgraded my **eclipse** to 4.7 to support **Java9**
After upgradation eclipse not loading pre-existing java application.
When I check run as **run as > run configuration** and double clicks on java application it throws

> An error has occurred. See error log for more details. tried to access
>   method
>   org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.getTabViewer()Lorg/eclipse/debug/internal/ui/launchConfigurations/LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer;
>   from class
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.LocalJavaApplicationTabGroup

Above error is gone after I downloaded [eclipse-oxygen1-a(which support java9 without any plugin)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Oxygen/1A.RC1) but still not able to run as java application. Getting this error on console

```
Error: Could not find or load main class 
       com.myclass.MyApplication
       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
                  com.myclass.MyApplication
```

I checked the error by built-in ErrorLog of Eclipse

> Window -> Show View -> General -> Error Log

Getting the following error

Session Data

```
eclipse.buildId=4.7.1.M20170922-1005
java.version=9
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -data file:/home/shekhar/git/ -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

Plug-In: org.eclipse.jdt.launching
Severity: Error
Message: Xbootclasspath option have been removed as not supported beyond Java 8.
```

Comment: There is already a thread for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452383/cant-add-java-applications-in-eclipse-run-configurations-after-upgrading-to-4-7 which is ultimatley a duplicated of another.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing JRE runtime environment in java 9 in eclipse oxygen version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46453241/choosing-jre-runtime-environment-in-java-9-in-eclipse-oxygen-version)...the answer there probably lists out the reason for such issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, publishing a patch feature to add Java 9 support to Oxygen.1 has introduced some complexity regarding combinations of installed versions, which has caused problems like the one reported here. While there are fixes for these problems, let me just add that the Oxygen.1a release scheduled for Oct. 11 should mend all these issues, as it is a real, patch-less release (also containing some bug fixes not contained in the patch feature).

Comment: @ChandraShekharYadav Did you try this with upgrading to the latest [eclipse package](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/) Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) which is marked as released and supports Java 9?

Comment: @nullpointer, Yes! I  upgraded to latest eclipse, already mentioned the eclipse link in the question.

Comment: **NOTE**: when upgrading to Eclipse Oxygen.1a make sure you have no left-overs from a previously installed BETA Patch feature! To find out check if version of plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.core is 3.13.50.v20171007-0855. If it is older, look under "Installed Software", find any "BETA Patch" feature for JDT and uninstall it.